# Express.js + body-parser: empty req.body from POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am using [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) and [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware to process incoming requests. On the front end, I have a form that's just a hidden input and a submit button (written in Pug):

```
form(notes="saveNotesForm" action=`/lessons/${lesson._id}/notes` method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
              input(type="hidden" id="hiddenNotes" name="hiddenNotes" alt="Notes Copy" value="test").notesHidden
              input(type="submit" name="saveNotes" alt="Save Notes" value="Save")
```

On the backend, I have the Express app using body-parser:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// ...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And the route processing the incoming request:

```
router.post('/lessons/:lessonID/notes', lessonController.updateNotes);

// ... and in lessonController:

exports.updateNotes = async (req, res) => {
  console.log('updateNotes request received');
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
}
```

When I try to use `req.body` in `updateNotes`, the body is an empty object, but should at least have the property `hiddenNotes` with the value `"test"`. Please comment if you have any questions or think you see the problem!

**[UPDATED]**

This was a silly mistake, I forgot I had written a separate event handler for when this form gets submitted - it just took me posting on SO before I went through all of my code :) The event handler uses [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and looks like this:

```
const SaveNotesButton = $('form.saveNotes');
SaveNotesButton.on('submit', ajaxSaveNotes);

function ajaxSaveNotes(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios
    .post(this.action)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Unfortunately, when making `post`s with axios, you need to include the data in an object like this, or else it won't be included in the request:

```
const SaveNotesButton = $('form.saveNotes');
SaveNotesButton.on('submit', ajaxSaveNotes);

function ajaxSaveNotes(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios
    .post(this.action, { notes: this.children.hiddenNotes.value }) // Data added here
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `bodyParser.urlencoded` to be called before `bodyParser.json`. Not sure if it makes any difference, but I wrote my own middleware to capture the raw body request so I do not lose anything and I found that after `bodyPaser.json`, the `req.on('end')` event had already fired, preventing me from recording the data. Putting my middleware before that (and some other changes) allowed me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried querying your end point using Postman or something similar?

Comment: Yep, I tried recreating the request in Postman, and the body still didn't show any data.

Answer (score 0):

There could be one possible explanation for why your `req.body` is undefined. Are you sure your `app.use(bodyParser.json())` and `app.use(bodyParser.url...` are written before your `app.use('***', router)` lines? If you put the body parser middleware AFTER your router middleware it essentially won't get called because middleware are called in the order they are put in `app.use`. So you should place your `bodyParser` before all your router logic. BodyParser middleware then calls all the other middleware (with the `req.body` populated) that come after it including all your router level middleware.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Mustansir! Yeah, I am `app.use`-ing bodyParser a few lines before the routes are included on the app.

Comment: Did you ever try to change the content-type to application/json?

Comment: I hadn't tried changing the enctype - [but I made a very obvious mistake](https://media.giphy.com/media/eY3PhUq1mfyWA/giphy.gif), unrelated to the code I included in this post. Take a glance at my updates to the OP in a second!

Comment: Oh. In that case great!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are defining your routes but I would expect a post route to look like the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/lessons/:lessonID/notes', (req, res) => {
    // now pass the req object to your function
    lessonController.updateNotes(req);
});
```

You need to pass the req object to your function to be able to access req.body...

Comment: The express app's routes are just broken out into a separate file (rather than being on the same line as `app.post`), the lessonController.updateNotes function receives the req and res objects.

Comment: [I made a very obvious mistake](https://media.giphy.com/media/eY3PhUq1mfyWA/giphy.gif), unrelated to the code I included in this post. Take a glance at my updates to the OP!

Comment: Glad you sorted it!